# set cookie if user presses the closeBtn

Tags: javascript, cookies

If usser has closed the popup via closeBtn dont show it again till tomorrow.
And if it is posible to make it show popup after 2 visited pages. The setTimeout for the start is ok.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
    if (check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
        setTimeout("beginNewsletterForm()", 120000);
    }

    $('#newsletter_popup_dont_show_again').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).length) {
            var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
            if (check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'dontshowitagain');
            }
            else {
                $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
                setTimeout("beginNewsletterForm()", 120000);
            }
        } else {
            $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
        }
    });
});

function beginNewsletterForm() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'padding': '0px',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#newsletter_popup',
        'onComplete': function () {
            $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
        },
        'tpl': {
            closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancybox-newsletter-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
        }
    });
    jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function in JAVASCRIPT that checks whether you already shown your popup message or not along with the getCookie function and setCookie

```
//execute this function when your document loads
popupChecker();

function popupChecker()
{
   if(getCookie("popup") != "true")
   {
        //show pop up
   }
}

//chage closeBtnId with your close btn ID

$("closeBtnId").click()
{
    //set cookie that expires in 1 day
    setCookie("popup", "true", 1);
}
```

This is the function for get and set of cookies paste this to your .JS file or just create new CLASS of Cookie for clean codes.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
{
   var d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}


function getCookie(cname) 
{
   var name = cname + "=";
   var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
   var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
   for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) 
   {
     var c = ca[i];
     while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
     {
        c = c.substring(1);
     }
     if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
     {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
     }
   }
return "";
}
```

What do you mean in "And if it is posible to make it show popup after 2 visited pages" ? on my understanding you want to check if the user already visited in your page twice? and if yes? you want to show the pop up message. so i just modify the popChecker and the click event of the closeBtn.

```
function popupChecker()
{
   if(getCookie("popup") == "true")
   {
      //check if visit count is equals to 2 
     if(getCookie("visit_count") == "2")
     {
        //show pop up
     }

   }else
   {
       //show pop up and add 1 to visit_count cookie
       var visitCount = getCookie("visit_count");
       setCookie("visit_count", visitCount + 1, 1);
   }
 }

//chage closeBtnId with your close btn ID

$("closeBtnId").click()
{
   setCookie("popup", "true", 1);
   setCookie("visit_count", "1", 1);
}
```

For more understanding in Cookies using JS you can visit this site
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Ty very much. On the "And if it is posible to make it show popup after 2 visited pages" i ment if a user stays on the website and surfs 2-3 pages than show the popup.

Comment: Your welcome. so you want to pop up when the user select other page? what you can do is everytime the user click on a link or button on other page add the get the visit_count cookie and add 1 then call the popup checker again. just modify the code and it will help you alot!